# Kafka in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-kafka

I am trying to use the code from a youtube tutorial to set up Kafka with Eclipse. The thing is I finally managed to set up the servers and the code, as far as my knowledge goes, seems fine to me. The problem is that I have to import files from Kafka to make the program work and it seems there has been a problem with the module dependencies. I already looked up some questions which told me to install new software which I did and it still does not work.

The code looks like this

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class Produce {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // properties for producer
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        // create Producer
        Producer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<Integer,String>(props);
        
        // send messages to my topic
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        ProducerRecord<Integer, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<Integer, String>("Test Topic", i, "Test Message #" +  Integer.toString(i));
        producer.send(producerRecord);
        }
            
        // close Producer
        
        producer.close();
    }
    }
```

and the error message is this :
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\adria\kafka_2.13-3.1.0\libs\jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.12.3.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jackson.module.scala.2.13: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier

I can understand somewhat but not enough to get anywhere near solving it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like you are using the Java module system, just deleting the 'module-info.java' to stop using that would be a quick fix.

Comment: Where can I find that file in Java?